# Difference between <stdafx.h> and "stdafx.h"

Tags: visual-c++

I have unit a.cpp that is used in several projects in subdirectory `libA`. Some of project are using precompiled headers, while others -not.  In this case projects that use precompiled header must have line:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

and projects that are not using PCH must have line:

```
#include "..\stdafx.h"
```

Wise verse is not working.

Why project sees stdafx.h file in different way when project uses PCH or not?

UPD.

When I replace line `#include <stdafx.h>` with `#include "..\stdafx.h"` in project that uses precompiled header i have error

```
Error   19  error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

Directory structure is the same in both projects.

Comment: A different solution: put a.cpp into a library or DLL for re-use. Then you don't need to worry about precompiled header differences.

Comment: This might be solution, but I'm lazy to recompile libs in separate project each time I change them. And it is not nice :)

Comment: Add the library or DLL project to your other solutions and add a dependency. Once it is set up, no extra work needed! It *is* nice. Reused code belongs in libraries or DLLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Answer (score 0):

There is no (or there should not be any) difference between `<stdafx.h>` and `"stdafx.h"`. The only significant difference is that one project "sees" the file in current folder, and the other project sees it in parent folder. This difference is controlled by compiler option [Additional Include Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx). One project has `libA` in it, and the other does not have it.

Comment: Both projects has line .\libA\ in Additionl Include Directories. And both of them has a.cpp in these directories

Comment: @vico I got it wrong. Projects need path to `stdafx.h`, not to `libA`. So, one project has that directory (could be as simple as `.`, or maybe `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(SolutionDir)`), and the other does not have it.

Comment: Both projects has the same lines in Additional Include Directories.